# Scilab Graph Axis Title with Greek Letters

Tags: graph, scilab

How to add greek letters like  and LaTeX like equations at Scilab chart axis titles.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite easy, use double dollars:

```
legend("$$\varphi(t)$$")
```

You may have to play with size to have the desired rendering, i.e.

```
legend("$$\large\varphi(t)$$")
```

Comment: Hello Stéphane, thanks for the answer. It work but only for `$$\varphi$$` solely. Using it on the y-axis as a combined string it shows up like this: `f($$\varphi$$,t)`. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, got it myself. Using a combined string together with the greek symbol the complete string has to be wrapped in `$$...$$`, e.g. `"$$f(\varphi,t)$$"`. Thank you very much.

Comment: Unlike Matlab you cannot mix LaTeX and non-LaTeX,  hence when you need a LaTeX rendering you have to render the whole string, ylabel("$$f\(varphi,t)$$") is the only way. To mix upright fonts use \mathrm.

Comment: Ok, looking really good now. Thanks! By the way, using Scilab branch 6.1 requires only single `$` signs before and after the string.